# How to get device current latitude and longitude for IPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-location

I'm developing an app were I would like to get device current latitude and longitude for IPhone. Is it possible to obtain this information without using GPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `CoreLocation framework`

The Core Location framework has one important class `CLLocationManager`.

The `CLLocationManager` class handles sending out updates to a delegate anytime the location is changed.  it uses the delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol.

you can use it like

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
  <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
  CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}
```

set up locationManager like this in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

implement the below delegate mehod for getting changed location

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  NSInteger degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
  int minutes = decimal * 60;
  double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *lattitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];
  lattitudeLabel.text = lattitudeStr;
  degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
  minutes = decimal * 60;
  seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *longitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
  longitudeLabel.text = longitudeStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CLLocationManager` to get current lat and long.
create an `iVar` of `CLLocationManager` and use it.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

currentLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
currentLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
CLLocation* currentLocation = [locationManager location];

NSString *loc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"location:%@", loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current location without GPS by using CLLocationManager if the device has WiFi or cellular data service.  The location will not be as accurate as you would get from GPS but you get a result faster than from GPS.

You can request a non-GPS location from CLLocationManager by setting the desiredAccuracy property to kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift

```
import CoreLocation
```

Get current location

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

//get the most recently retrieved user location
if let currentLocation = locationManager.location {
    let longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    //work with the received data
}
```

Note that `locationManager.location` is an optional and hence should be safely unwrapped.